# CrystalReports Editing a rpt file

Tags: crystal-reports, editing

I was asked to investigate why some data is not being pulled up in a CrytalReport document. I am an absolute beginner ( as far as CrytalReports is concerned ) who just wanted to tinker with the code and see how the results change. Is this right way to fix the issue?

I was thinking that there will be some selection criteria (similar to an SQL Query ) and I can change the values there. After spending a couple of hours, I am out of patience. Can anyone please tell me or give me some pointers about them. I prefer not going through CrystalReports for beginners which teach from installing to setup and all. In fact, I really don't know what it takes to edit a CrystalReports file.

Another issue is that when I open the .rpt file, I get a dialog with the title `Log On To Repository`. Which repository is this? I have complete access to the SQL Server database, but the passwords did not work..(including that of sa )

I have VS(2010/2003), CR Developer 9.2.3.1699.

All suggestions are greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where to start...

1. The `Log on to repository` thingy is referring to the shared repository if BusinessObjects Enterprise.  You seem to have the standalone version, so don't worry about that.
2. Press F1 for help.  The help files are fairly good.  Not great, but good.
3. Try **Report->Selection Formulas-Record**.  This limits the individual records going into the report by that criteria.  Likewise with **Report->Selection Formulas->Group**
4. **Database->Verify Database** (Self-explanatory)
5. **Database->Database Expert** and **Database->Set Datasource Location**  are both very helpful in figuring out where the report gets it's data from.
6. This is a full-featured program.  When I first saw it, it took me 3 months to get a decent working knowledge.  You won't learn the details of it overnight.

Comment: +1 Also, **Database->Show SQL Query...** does exactly what it says - by copying and pasting into a query tool, you can see exactly what data the report is selecting.

Comment: My initial hurdle was that this report was being pulled by using a calling a stored procedure!!., and when I clicked Database->Show SQL Query.. there was no "exec..", and I was stuck with it!..Thank you guys for helping me out :)